# Two Azure VMs: one sends mail, other's mail bounces

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, azure

An Ubuntu 16 VM (call it admin1) in westus2 region can send a test mail to gmail that is received. A virtually identical VM (call it admin2) in southcentralus has its email bounced. Email to yahoo.com reports IP is rejected by Spamhaus. Spamhaus lists the IP on its PBL: SMTP authentication required. SASL configuration on admin2 is not yet successful as determined by testsaslauth.

There are slight but noticeable differences between the two: admin1 requires a password for `sudo ...`, admin2 does not. Output of `service postfix status` is slightly different. Line by line comparison of postfix main.cf shows no difference except for host names.

The only requirement for email on either server is for php to send an email to tech support if an exception occurs. The only reason admin2 exists is that Azure backup is not available in westus2. If email worked on admin2, westus2 would be abandoned. The regions selected are constrained by the terms of the grant that allows the use of Azure resources. A third-party smart host is not a viable option - the systems are for a small nonprofit with a tiny budget but a wonderful Microsoft grant.

Can admin2 ever send mail that doesn't bounce?

Comment: postfix can't work in this way. maybe we can deploy a cluster to run the postfix, in this way to achieve high availability.

Comment: Cluster? High availability? How this solves either the backup issue on admin1 or the email issue on admin2 escapes me. This question is now moot - the entire installation in southcentralus has been deleted. An automated mysql backup solution now exists on admin1.

Comment: @ geoB, Do you mean you want to find a way to backup admin1? As a workaround, maybe we can try to copy the admin1 VHD to another storage account, or use third party tools.

Comment: Admin1 is constrained by the terms of the Microsoft grant to be in a subset of regions.  Because the nonprofit is in the western US the westus2 region seemed most appropriate.  Adding backup was the last piece to be added but is not available in westus2. I tried southcentralus but could not get as far as I did with admin1. There is no interest in trying a third region. Besides, the process of copying a VHD is more complex than simply recreating a VM. I consider the entire question closed.